# Pydantic V2 error using FastAPI + SQLModel

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

I don't understand why my code won't work??

Is there a bug fix out that can help me with this issue?

```
Error Message: PydanticImportError(f'`{import_path}` has been removed in V2.')
pydantic.errors.PydanticImportError: `pydantic.errors:ConfigError` has been removed in V2.
```

Main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, status
from database import engine, create_db
from sqlmodel import Session, select
from models import Tickets
from typing import Optional, List

app = FastAPI()

create_db()

db_session = Session(bind= engine)

@app.route('/tickets', response_model = List[Tickets], status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def get_all_tickets():
    statement = select(Tickets)

    all_tickets = statement.all()

    return all_tickets
```

Model.py

```
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, create_engine
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Tickets(SQLModel, table=True):
    id : int = Field(primary_key=True)
    subject : str 
    description : str
```

database.py

```
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, create_engine

DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:bigsql@localhost:5432/FastAPIDB"

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL, echo=True)

def create_db():
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I was told to downgrade my version of pydantic? Not sure if that will help or not

Comment: What is your FastAPI version?

Comment: fastapi              0.103.1

Comment: Weird, it supports Pydantic V2. What is your exact version of Pydantic? Did you install Pydantic manually or let FastAPI install it as a dependency?

Comment: SQLModel is not compatible with Pydantic V2 (see [this issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/532)).

Comment: @Selcuk I used pip install "FastAPI[ALL]" and then used pip install SQLModel

Answer (score 0):

As @M.O. mentioned in the comments, `SQLModel` is not compatible with Pydantic V2:

https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/532

In this case you can do a

```
pip install "pydantic<2"
```

to downgrade it. Your FastAPI version is also compatible with Pydantic V1.